# How do I hide commands that are executed in NppExec?

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

I'm wondering if I can disable the console info, or the green text, that shows up in the NppExec console when I run `npe_console v+`.

This is what I see when I run my script:

```
Console mode: a- d+ h- m- q+ v+ f- r- k3 o2 i2
; append: off, cd_curdir: on, cmd_history: off
; int_msgs: off, cmd_aliases: on, output_var: on
; filter: off, replace_filter: off
; shortcut_keys: std+usr
; out_enc: UTF8, in_enc: UTF8
Exists
```

The intended output is 'Exists' - I'm wondering if I can hide this? Something along the lines of `npe_console v+ >nul` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered it. If you enclose the parts of your script that you do not want to see in the console in `NPP_CONSOLE -` and then `NPP_CONSOLE +`, it hides it from the console.

So doing

```
echo Hello
NPP_CONSOLE -
npe_console +v
cmd /c echo There
npe_console -v
NPP_CONSOLE +
echo World
```

outputs the following to the console:

```
Hello
World
```

Without the aforementioned `NPP_CONSOLE` commands, the above would show:

```
Hello
Console mode: a- d+ h- m- q+ v+ f- r- k3 o2 i2
; append: off, cd_curdir: on, cmd_history: off
; int_msgs: off, cmd_aliases: on, output_var: on
; filter: off, replace_filter: off
; shortcut_keys: std+usr
; out_enc: UTF8, in_enc: UTF8
There
Console mode: a- d+ h- m- q+ v+ f- r- k3 o2 i2
; append: off, cd_curdir: on, cmd_history: off
; int_msgs: off, cmd_aliases: on, output_var: on
; filter: off, replace_filter: off
; shortcut_keys: std+usr
; out_enc: UTF8, in_enc: UTF8
World
```